# Python - Como obter a saída da execução de um arquivo .py para um .txt

Tags: python-3.x, linux

Eu tenho o seguinte comando:

`python3 -u teste.py > saida.txt 2>&1`

Este comando faz com que a saída da execução do arquivo de `teste.py` seja enviado para este arquivo `saida.txt`, caso `saida.txt` não exista ele é criado. O `teste.py` nunca para sua execução por se tratar de uma [Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), ou seja, o arquivo de `teste.py` está sempre tentando escrever novas informações na `saida.txt`, o que faz com que, ao tentar editar o arquivo `saida.txt` enquanto `teste.py`está em execução, perca-se a referência e ele para de preencher o arquivo de `saida.txt`com as informações da execução do `teste.py`.

Ao falhar em tentar editar o arquivo `saida.txt` desta maneira, eu optei por outro método usando python3:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import subprocess as sp

class teste(Thread):
    def __init__(self):

        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.cmd  = ['python3 -u teste.py']
        self.proc = sp.Popen(self.cmd, shell = True,
                                     stdout=sp.PIPE,
                                     stderr=sp.PIPE,
                                     stdin=sp.PIPE)        

    def run(self):

        while True:

            sleep(1)

            self.output = self.proc.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
            self.error  = self.proc.stderr.read().decode('utf-8')        
            print(self.output)
            print(self.error)

            # Caso eu conseguisse ler a saída eu passaria estas informações
            # Para um arquivo .txt

et = teste()
et.start()
```

Porém não obtive sucesso em ler a saída do `teste.py` através dos prints, não gerou-se resultados e nenhum tipo de erro.

O conteúdo do `teste.py` é bem simples, seria algo como:

```
from time import sleep

while 1:
    print('saída')
    sleep(1)
```

OBS: As demasiadas citações ao `teste.py` e `saida.txt` foram intencionais para deixar claro o processo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, `self.proc.stdout.read()`, irá bloquear sua chamada até que o programa se encerre, e por isso você não recebe nada.

Para fazer o que você quer, são necessário duas threads, como se segue:

```
def print_lines(inp):
    line = inp.readline().decode('utf-8')
    while line:
        print(line, end='')
        line = inp.readline().decode('utf-8')

proc = sp.Popen(['python3 -u teste.py'], shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE)

t1 = Thread(target=print_lines, args=(proc.stdout,))
t2 = Thread(target=print_lines, args=(proc.stderr,))

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

[Nessa publicação](http://tbrink.science/blog/2017/04/30/processing-the-output-of-a-subprocess-with-python-in-realtime/), você pode encontrar uma versão *single threaded*, lendo dos dois *streams* utilizando [*pseudo-terminal utilities*](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/pty.html), aparentemente por um problema de *bufferização* (tempo de resposta da leitura) na solução conforme acima propus.

Abaixo deixo também, outro `teste.py` incluindo escrita em `stderr`:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

for _ in range(5):
    print('saída')
    sleep(0.3)

sys.stderr.write("acabou\n")
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado :)